# Obtaining data from SQLite file C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hi guys can somebody instruct me on how to solve this problem. I am connecting to a database in the bin debug file whilst using SQLite. I want to check if the login details of the user are correct and when the code verifies that the login details are correct I want to check if the person has registered as a administrator or in this case lecturer however when I don't know how to pull the data from the specific user that has logged in to check if they are a lecturer. There is my code:

```
string Query = string.Format("SELECT [username], [password], [isLecturer] FROM users");

            SQLiteConnection DataBaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
            SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, DataBaseConnection);
            DataBaseConnection.Open();
            using (var reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((reader.GetString(0) == txtUsername.Text) && (reader.GetString(1) == txtpassword.Text))
                    {
                        string Query2 = string.Format("SELECT [isLecturer] FROM users WHERE ");
                        if ((reader.GetString(2) == "1"))
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            FetchingTheMainConwaysForm(1);
                        }
                        else if ((reader.GetString(2) == "0"))
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            FetchingTheMainConwaysForm(0);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect", "Authentication Problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
            DataBaseConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting whole table in the code. This will make your app slow. I will suggest to send user name and password to the database like below

SELECT [username], [password], [isLecturer] FROM users WHERE [username]=txtUsername.Text AND [password]=txtpassword.Text

If this query returns a row this means it is a successful login otherwise show error message to user.

Now, for successful login use that selected columns through out the code.

My suggestion, Don't use column like [isLecturer]. Make it Role and add values like administrator, lecturer, student etc. (Standard way is to create one more table with RoleId and Role, and use that RoleId in your main table) So in future you can add more roles without doing any more changes in code. You can easily compare user role and give privileges/features depending on role.

And add trim and more validations.